# Grails 3 run-app doesn't return after bootRun

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I've been using the Grails 3.0.1 interactive console, and when I type the "run-app" command, I expected it to start the server and return to the prompt. Instead it did something like:

```
grails> run-app
> Configuring > 1/1 projects > Resolving dependencies ':agent' > Resolving dependencies ':versio
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Building 16% > :compileGroovy > Resolving dependencies ':compile' > Resolving dependencies 'de
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
> Building 83% > :bootRun > Resolving dependencies ':runtime' > Resolving dependencies 'detached:bootRun
Grails application running at http://localhost:8080
> Building 83% > :bootRun
```

at which point the system waits until I hit Ctrl-C. I thought the system would start and then return to the prompt. Am I missing something obvious? Do I just need to wait it out?

Comment: I have been running my apps via gradle not the grails interactive prompt and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Same problem here. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: The title says "run-app doesn't return after bootRun".  I understand the problem with the console not returning, but are you saying that the app doesn't actually run?

Comment: The app runs, but locks up the console so the only way to stop it is ctrl-c. In previous versions you got the prompt back even while running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [inherited bug](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/641) from spring boot which is now fixed and will be available in next version probably 3.0.3.